# How do I fix 'nan'

Tags: math, bbc-microbit

I am not sure why this is returning nan and what to do.

```
    g = accelerometer.get_z()
    G = (6.67*10)**-11
    m = (5.972*10)**24
    c = 299792458
    r = 38.5*(5.972*10)**24/ g* G
    deltatgprime = 5 * math.sqrt(1 - (2 * G * m / r * c**2))
    display.scroll(deltatgprime)
```

Comment: I'm going to guess `G = (6.67*10)**-11` should be `G = 6.67*(10**-11)` and similarly `m = (5.972*10)**24` should be `m = 5.972*(10**24)` and similarly `r = 38.5*(5.972*10)**24/ g* G` should be `r = 38.5*m/ g* G` or maybe even possibly `r = 38.5*m/ (g* G)`?

Comment: And probably `deltatgprime = 5 * math.sqrt(1 - (2 * G * m / r * c**2))` should be `deltatgprime = 5 * math.sqrt(1 - 2 * G * m / (r * c**2))`?

Comment: Parentheses are **important**.